# tcpdump output to file not working

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write the results of tcpdump to a text file. I am not interested in saving a pcap file to use later, I just need exactly what tcpdump returns in plain text (the ips and timestamps of connections).

I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
tcpdump port 5000 and '(tcp-syn)!=0' > network_output.txt
```

This command should save to the textfile but instead it echo's the output right in the termial as if I left the `> network_output.txt` off.

Comment: What did you mean by `and '(tcp-syn)!=0'`? Should it be a comparison, then you forgot to make it a var: `and [[ ${tcp-syn} -ne 0 ]]`.

Comment: I'm not sure. I didn't know what it did either but a friend told me to use it.

Comment: Then, why not just `tcpdump port 5000 > ...`?

Comment: Well sure I can, but its still not writing to the file.

Comment: Use `tcpdump port 5000 &> network_output.txt`. This shall redirect both stdout and stderr to your file. Andalso, you seem to be running `tcpdump` with incorrect arguments. Use `man tcpdump` for reference.

Comment: It did seem to write 'listening on venet0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 96 bytes' to the text file, but its not writing the results when clients connect.

Comment: This is very strange, the command works perfectly well on my Debian as well. Please update your question to include your distribution and `tcpdump` version (`tcpdump -h`). You _are_ running this as `root` right?

Answer (score 0):

What operating system and shell are you using?  (Your command works fine for me on my system.)

Try `tcpdump  port 5000 and '(tcp-syn)!=0' &> network_output.txt` (notice `&>` instead of `>`) and see if that does what you want.  It combines the Standard Output with the Error Output into one file. Although it's called the Error Output, that second output stream is often used for output meant for an interactive terminal such as progress information.

If that doesn't work, try:

```
script network_output.txt
tcpdump  port 5000 and '(tcp-syn)!=0'
```

then Ctrl-C to quit `tcpdump` and Ctrl-D to exit `script`.  You will get extra junk in the file but it will have all the terminal output as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is interesting. It 'did' work or so I thought, as the 'listening on port 5000...' got written to the text file, but when I make a connection the '0.0.0.0 has connected ..' that its supposed to be also written isnt. when I do the command by iteslf I have many lines coming up as clients connect, but it doesn't seem to be doing that when I write it to the file.. PS I'm using CentOS 5.9

Comment: Try using `script`.